# Difference between name.html.erb vs name.erb

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, erb

What is the difference between `name.html.erb` vs `name.erb`?
In particular, are there any reasons why `name.erb` could be bad to use?

I understand that `name.html.erb` is the convention - this indicates a HTML template and ERB Engine. But I can't find information if are there any reasons not to use `name.html.erb`, but `name.erb` instead.

My new workplace asks me to use `name.erb`, so I want to know: might there be any problems with this?

Answer (score 3):

In short, no, there won't be any problems. Erb files simply output text. In many cases the file extension is ignored by the reading app as the reading app reads/interprets the containing text and its syntax validity. As @taglia suggests, the file extensions are mostly a 'hint' for you and may also be used by the OS to select a default app to open the file with. See here for a more thorough explanation: [Output Type for an ERB File](https://www.reddit.com/r/rails/comments/31cq8s/what_is_the_default_output_type_for_an_erb_file/)

Rails convention dictates template files to include the extension of the output type and the name of the file should end with the *.erb* extension. As you mentioned, *name.html.erb* indicates an HTML template and ERB extension that allows any instance variables in your controller's index action to get passed into the template and used. Similarly, *name.js.erb* indicates a JavaScript template. See here under 'Conventions or Template Files': [An Introduction to ERB Templating](http://www.stuartellis.eu/articles/erb/)

Answer (score -1):

ERB is just a templating language, it is not limited to HTML (you could have `name.txt.erb`, or `name.js.erb`). Removing `html` from the name is just going to make your life more difficult (assuming it works), because you won't be able to know what file you are dealing with unless you open it.

Comment: Well, they say it works, and they only don't use it for `html`. So they use `.js.erb`, etc.. I wanted to know if there might be any errors in the future.. or is it just an visual thing for developers?

Comment: If it works you should be fine with the current major version of rails. Difficult to say for the future though.